# Force file download with header is corrupting file

Tags: php

So I am using PHP headers to force download a file, but when the file is saved it gets corrupted because for whatever reason the HTML code from the download page is also added into the file code/contents:

Beginning of downloaded file:
[image]

End of downloaded file:
[image]

and here is my code that forces the download, I also downloaded the same file straight from my server (FTP) and it does not have this in its file code, so I know it has to be the following code causing the problem:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$qfile['rfname']}");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file['dl_path']);
```

I've looked around but I don't see anything pertaining to this, would anybody have an idea as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Exit the script after this so you don't fall through to the HTML code.

Comment: Put the download code in it's own PHP file that only contains that code and call that instead of putting it in the same file you have your HTML.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I would still need to `include` or `require` that "PHP file", so it really wouldn't do anything. Like @Barmar said, I completely skipped over the `exit()` function causing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Barmar said, I needed to `exit();`/`die();` after the function `readfile();`.

So the fix would look like:

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$qfile['rfname']}");
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file['dl_path']);
exit(); // Or you can use die(); here
```

Answer (score 0):

Add content type to application/octet-stream as below:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
```